# C# - log4net in .Net Core through multiple APIs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, log4net

I have many WebApi projects and a "Host" Api project that manage the requests for other APIs. I'm trying to use log4net between this projects. In my Host project it's working fine, but in others project not.

The problem is, only my Host project is started when I run the Solution, others projects only have the business logic. So I have the follow code on Startup of Host:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider service)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
}
```

In other projects, I can't put this in Startup, because this projects not start like Host. How can I use log4net in my projects? I would like to use one Appender per project.

Comment: What are the type of `other projects`? Are they class libraries?

Comment: @Win no, they are Web Api projects, that's why I can set log4net on Startup